# How to delete first row in SQLITE Database?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, listview

My ListView shows data from my SQLITE Database.
By Longclick on a ListViewItem I delete this specific Item.
EveryThing works fine, but I don't get my first item deleted. I don't get any Errors in LogCat or something. Just nothing happens.

Here is my code from the **Database class**:

```
public void deleteEntry(String TABLE, int pos) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.delete(TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=?" , new String[] { String.valueOf(pos)});

    // also tryed this code
    database.delete(TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "= '" + pos +"'",null);
}
```

Here is the code of my **ListView activity**:

```
// Deletes the given row
            database.deleteEntry(MyDatabase.DATABASE_TABLE_ORDERS, position);
            updateList();
```

I'm quite shure that the committed **int pos** is representing the rowId of the respective Databse entry ( for the first entry **pos** is 0, for the second **pos** is 1 and so on )

**updateList()** creates a new listview and loads all the data from the DB again

Has anybody got an idea why i can delete all my Items in the ListView / rows in my DB besides my first entry? thx for your help!

Comment: It has to work. Try with debugging points to trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through your question a couple times I think what I initially posed in my comment is the issue...

It appears to me that you are using the `int pos` parameter and thinking that it is the row id in the DB, that is not the case.  The `int pos` parameter is the position in the list (which can be different from the row id depending on your sort, etc).

The row id is contained in the `long id` parameter of the listener.  The following changes should help you out (assuming my guess is correct).

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
       database.deleteEntry(MyDatabase.DATABASE_TABLE_ORDERS, id);  
       updateList();  
}

public void deleteEntry(String TABLE, long id) {   
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();   
    database.delete(TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=?" , new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});   

    // or this could be used
    database.delete(TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "= " + id ,null);   
}
```

Comment: That is really helpfull. Thx!!!!!!!! Didn't know that the **long id** parameter is for the database. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE + " ORDER BY " + column_to_order_by + " ASC LIMIT(0,1);"):

I would definitly test this on a test table first!

Comment: An `ORDER BY` clause might be useful to sort the table such that the "first row" has meaning.

Comment: You could also assign a Row Number to each entry (it's index in the table) and then you could execute "DELETE FROM " + Table + "WHERE ROW_ID = " + pos

Comment: limit(0,1) is not supported - just use limit(1)